# If statement on MySQL results with different order

Tags: php, sql, arrays

I try to use an if statement on my query results.

Below an example of my database tables

```
+----+-------------+-----------+
| ID | post_title  | post_type |
| 1  | first post  | product   |
| 2  | second post | product   |
+----+-------------+-----------+

+---------+---------+---------------+------------+
| meta_id | post_id | meta_key      | meta_value |
| 1       | 1       | _price        | 16.50      |
| 2       | 1       | _manage_stock | yes        |
| 3       | 1       | _stock        | 4          |
| 4       | 2       | _stock        | 9          |
| 5       | 2       | _price        | 14.95      |
| 6       | 2       | _manage_stock | yes        |
+---------+---------+---------------+------------+
<?php
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
    if (false === isset($data[$row['ID']])) {
        $data[$row['ID']] = array(
            'id'            => $row['ID'],
            'post_title'    => $row['post_title'],
            'price'         => '-',
            'stock'         => 'geen voorraad'
        );

    }

    if($row['meta_key'] == '_price' ){
        if($row['meta_value'] !== ''){  
            $data[$row['ID']]['price']   = $row['meta_value'];
        }else{
            $data[$row['ID']]['price'] = '-';
        }
    }

    if($row['meta_key'] == '_stock_status' ){
        $data[$row['ID']]['stock_status'] = $row['meta_value'];
    }

     if($row['meta_key'] == '_manage_stock' ){
        if($row['meta_value'] == 'yes'){
            if($row['meta_key'] == '_stock' ){
                $data[$row['ID']]['stock'] = $row['meta_value'];
            }
        }   
     }
}
?>
```

I want the _stock value in the array if the _manage_stock value is yes
I added this to my code

```
 if($row['meta_key'] == '_manage_stock' ){
     if($row['meta_value'] == 'yes'){
         if($row['meta_key'] == '_stock' ){
             $data[$row['ID']]['stock'] = $row['meta_value'];
         }
     }  
 }
```

But this works only if the _manage_stock key is above _stock key in the database.
If the _stock record is earlier in the database that the _manage_stock record this if statement will not work.

Comment: Can you explain how `meta_key` can be `_manage_stock` and `_stock` at the same time?

Comment: _manage_stock and _stock are different from each other. If the manage_stock is yes the function for how many are there in stock is active. _stock is storage how many there in stock. But the system put this random in the database what I explain above.

Comment: Please show us your existing query, and the result that you are looking for, as tabular text. It is very possible that what you want can be done directly in SQL, without any PHP code.

Comment: _“_manage_stock and _stock are different from each other”_ - that was not what Petro was trying to ask you. You go `if($row['meta_key'] == '_manage_stock' )` in the code you have shown, and then two lines later, without `$row['meta_key']` getting _changed_ anywhere, `if($row['meta_key'] == '_stock' )` - it is _impossible_ for both of those conditions to be true at the same time, so this will _never_ get to the innermost line where you are trying to make your assigment.